# How to add tag for numbers which in brackets using python regex?

Tags: python, regex

The default strings is:

`strings123[abc123def456]strings456`

Add tag for number:

`strings[abc<span>123</span>def<span>456</span>]strings`

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your question to include your attempts.

Comment: Can `strings` also contain numbers, and if so, would you want them to be enclosed in `span` tags as well?

Answer (score 2):

Search by this:

```
(\d+)
```

and replace by :

```
<span>\1</span>
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/thRxTI/1)

Sample Source:

```
import re
regex = r"(\d+)"
test_str = "strings[abc123def456]strings"
subst = "<span>\\1</span>"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: This yields unexpected results when there are digits outside `[...]` - you might need `\G` which is only supported by the newer `regex` module.

Comment: ``strings123[abc<span>123</span>def<span>456</span>]strings456`` can't works well.