# Match in specific locations

Tags: python, regex

This is a follow-up of **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751849/how-to-add-tag-for-numbers-which-in-brackets-using-python-regex)** (not asked by me though). Trying to answer, I ran into a couple of problems.

Consider the string `strings123[abc789<span>123</span>def<span>456</span>000]strings456`, how would one match the digits in square brackets that are not surrounded by `span` tags in `Python` (using the newer `regex` module) ?
In the example string, this would be `789` and `000`.

---

I was fiddling around with `\G` like ([**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ClbtF3/1))

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)
[^\d\]]*
\K
\d+
```

and `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` ([**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ClbtF3/2/)):

```
<span>.*?</span>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
\d+
```

But was unable to combine both [**statements**](https://regex101.com/r/ClbtF3/3/):

```
<span>.*?</span>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
(?:
    (?:\G(?!\A)|\[)
    [^\d\]]*
    (\d+)
    [^\d\]]*
    \K
)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I can think of a multi step solution, is that okay ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things I like about [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) is that it supports *infinite-width lookbehind*:

> - Variable-length lookbehind
>
> A lookbehind can match a variable-length string.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'strings123[abc789<span>123</span>def<span>456</span>000]strings456'
>>> rx = r'(?<=\[[^][]*)(?:<span>[^<]*</span>(*SKIP)(?!)|\d+)(?=[^][]*])'
>>> regex.findall(rx, s)
['789', '000']
>>>
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=\[[^][]*)` - there must be a `[` followed with zero or more chars other than `]` and `[` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group start

  - `<span>[^<]*</span>(*SKIP)(?!)` - match a `<span>`, then 0+ chars other than `<` (with a `[^<]*` negated character class), and then a `</span>` and discard the match while staying at the match end position, and go on to look for the next match
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=[^][]*])` - there must be a `]` after zero or more chars other than `]` and `[` immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of an algorithm which is as follows.

1. Search for square brackets and contents within it and store result in a variable. Regex would be [`\[[^]]*\]`](https://regex101.com/r/VZWIV2/1).
2. Now search for `<span>` tags and replace it with `-` just for simplicity of next step. Regex would be [`(<span>.*?</span>)`](https://regex101.com/r/VZWIV2/3).
3. Now you will be left with contents of square brackets other than what was in `<span>` tags. Simply search with [`\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/VZWIV2/4) to match digits.

Comment: Thanks. Did not mention that I wanted to have *one* regex but still your algorithm works, of course.